# CAML query is returning all the list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml, camlviewfields

I have the following CAML query

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='RiskRequestID'/><Value Type='Text'>" + r.id + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
ListItemCollection oListItems = context.Site.RootWeb.GetList(UFSsiteUrl + "Lists/RiskManagement/").GetItems(camlQuery);
context.Load(oListItems);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

to get the item with the entered RiskRequestID.. currently instead of getting one item i am getting all the items inside the list.. any advice?

and the RiskRequestID is a SharePoint field of type Single Line of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`camlQuery.ViewXml` needs to contain a query wrapped in a `<View>` node:

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='RiskRequestID'/><Value Type='Text'>" + r.id + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><View>";
```

When you don't include `<View>`, the query is considered malformed and as a result, it returns all items.